# Python: Max & Min value on each hour

Tags: python, arrays, datetime, max, min

I have a array of 2x720. First column is datetime and second column is value. My data look like:-

```
[(datetime.datetime(2015,4,26,0,10),25.2),
(datetime.datetime(2015,4,26,0,20),25.1),
(datetime.datetime(2015,4,26,0,30),25.7),
(datetime.datetime(2015,4,26,0,40),23.2),
(datetime.datetime(2015,4,26,0,50),22.2),
(datetime.datetime(2015,4,26,0,60),29.2),
(datetime.datetime(2015,4,26,1,00),22.2),
(datetime.datetime(2015,4,26,1,10),21.2), ...]
```

All data are on the same date. I just want to organize data to prepare plot in candle stick by hour (only max, min, don't want to put open,close). I just want a data like this:-

```
[(datetime.datetime(2015,4,26,0,00),max in hour 0, min in hour 0),
(datetime.datetime(2015,4,26,1,00),max in hour 1, min in hour 1),    
(datetime.datetime(2015,4,26,2,00),max in hour 2, min in hour 2), ...
(datetime.datetime(2015,4,26,23,00),max in hour 23, min in hour 23)]
```

I'm a new Python and want to work with beautiful short script. Previousely, I work with C++ (long long ago) and I found that Python is more art than just programming. I try to search for the answer for a while but cannot find any answer match with my requirement. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want the end result to look like. Are those `max in hour 0` strings ? Exactly what's changed from the input?

Comment: Sorry, i want the maximum and minimum value to plot candle stick chart.

Comment: are there always 6 data points per hour? and is it always already ordered by time?

Comment: Please tell us what you already tried to code to solve the problem. Stackoverflow is no programming service...

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
```

1. Create the DataFrame and sort in time

   ```
   df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns = ['time', 'price']).sort('time')
   ```

Where d is the list of tuples from your input.

```
                 time  price
0 2015-04-26 00:10:00   25.2
1 2015-04-26 00:20:00   25.1
2 2015-04-26 00:30:00   25.7
3 2015-04-26 00:40:00   23.2
4 2015-04-26 00:50:00   22.2
5 2015-04-26 00:59:00   29.2
6 2015-04-26 01:00:00   22.2
7 2015-04-26 01:10:00   21.2
```

2. Create column with date and hour information

   ```
   df['day_hour'] = df.apply(lambda r: datetime.datetime(r['time'].year,    r['time'].month, r['time'].day, r['time'].hour,0), axis = 1)
   ```

```
                 time  price            day_hour
0 2015-04-26 00:10:00   25.2 2015-04-26 00:00:00
1 2015-04-26 00:20:00   25.1 2015-04-26 00:00:00
2 2015-04-26 00:30:00   25.7 2015-04-26 00:00:00
3 2015-04-26 00:40:00   23.2 2015-04-26 00:00:00
4 2015-04-26 00:50:00   22.2 2015-04-26 00:00:00
5 2015-04-26 00:59:00   29.2 2015-04-26 00:00:00
6 2015-04-26 01:00:00   22.2 2015-04-26 01:00:00
7 2015-04-26 01:10:00   21.2 2015-04-26 01:00:00
```

3. Drop the original 'time' column since it's not used in output

   ```
   df = df.drop('time', axis = 1)
   ```
4. Group the data by the date and hour

   ```
   dfgrouped = df.groupby('day_hour')
   ```
5. Get max/min value on each date_hour

   ```
   dfmax = dfgrouped.max()
   dfmin = dfgrouped.min()
   ```
6. Join max/min together on the same day_hour

   ```
   dfout = dfmax.join(dfmin, lsuffix='_max', rsuffix='_min')
   ```

```
>>> dfout
                     price_max  price_min
day_hour                                 
2015-04-26 00:00:00       29.2       22.2
2015-04-26 01:00:00       22.2       21.2
```

Comment: @Neilz when i am downloading the data into csv..its missing time column.. any fix for that.

Answer (score 0):

Since they're all on the same day, group by the hour, and then describe the groups.

```
 import datetime
 from collections import defaultdict     

 start_of_day = datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26)

 hour_to_values = defaultdict(list)
 for dt, value in your_list_of_values:
      hour_to_values[dt.hour].append(value)

 result = [(start_of_day + datetime.timedelta(hours=hour),
            min(values), max(values))
           for hour, values in hour_to_values.iteritems()]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes the list is already date ordered

```
output = []
current_hour = None
current_output = None
for point in data:
    phour = point[0].hour
    pvalue = point[1]
    if phour is current_hour:
        if pvalue < current_output[1]:
            current_output[1] = pvalue
        if pvalue > current_output[2]:
            current_output[2] = pvalue
    else:
        current_hour = phour
        output.append([point[0], pvalue, pvalue])
        current_output = output[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is just like that:

```
>>> arr
[[datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 0, 0), 0.9627101684867109], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 0, 20), 0.8894632247614254], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 0, 40), 0.1920554638586589], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 1, 0), 0.24394390686092926], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 1, 20), 0.9870880292994234], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 1, 40), 0.8154734773666351], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 2, 0), 0.5074101780070644], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 2, 20), 0.6211085118418351], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 2, 40), 0.1309246438480619], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 3, 0), 0.2042948575387714], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 3, 20), 0.90969148583095], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 3, 40), 0.9260473796075621], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 4, 0), 0.08180604335801178], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 4, 20), 0.9909948477818202], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 4, 40), 0.6306008554115328], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 5, 0), 0.7218791510465083], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 5, 20), 0.5751211758007434], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 5, 40), 0.8643323785674638], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 6, 0), 0.44366887986412196], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 6, 20), 0.5845914793227223], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 6, 40), 0.9816449110831348], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 7, 0), 0.7976769524401801], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 7, 20), 0.019715644725192494], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 7, 40), 0.774857573501942], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 8, 0), 0.971010849289862], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 8, 20), 0.9854650056341737], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 8, 40), 0.44764478642480565], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 9, 0), 0.41757419665518836], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 9, 20), 0.2428205990660569], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 9, 40), 0.7652296383460859], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 10, 0), 0.6148904798625167], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 10, 20), 0.5437523646936837], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 10, 40), 0.7867821039231312], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 11, 0), 0.7178834338473005], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 11, 20), 0.4349509857268635], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 11, 40), 0.2819549901100772], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 12, 0), 0.0849398640248602], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 12, 20), 0.6260259998494316], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 12, 40), 0.8353818765863841], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 13, 0), 0.17232607867607763], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 13, 20), 0.17091634151665247], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 13, 40), 0.7653484731068122], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 14, 0), 0.9510280942218504], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 14, 20), 0.2696780695726898], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 14, 40), 0.6634142333370054], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 15, 0), 0.48395825825107863], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 15, 20), 0.7669839652095866], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 15, 40), 0.9479268674677883], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 16, 0), 0.9046641495205922], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 16, 20), 0.045289391652820865], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 16, 40), 0.7932951067126703], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 17, 0), 0.4419846953059643], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 17, 20), 0.11146542138230242], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 17, 40), 0.5887496294547572], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 18, 0), 0.08733136331114111], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 18, 20), 0.7957160332912587], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 18, 40), 0.8128833057460692], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 19, 0), 0.21977323027233342], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 19, 20), 0.20504702851137402], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 19, 40), 0.6555892081746738], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 20, 0), 0.7380315441194354], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 20, 20), 0.8075383278433004], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 20, 40), 0.837007721004194], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 21, 0), 0.8842141478652727], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 21, 20), 0.3349342531521037], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 21, 40), 0.811383235093619], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 22, 0), 0.8273356582091318], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 22, 20), 0.17269590855559502], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 22, 40), 0.13561711047456493], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 23, 0), 0.8906156794457442], [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 23, 20), 0.2653437814631542]]
```

(I replicated it with random data for the second element) you can place into buckets by hour:

```
>>> buckets={}
>>> for t in arr: 
...    buckets.setdefault(t[0].hour, []).append(t)
```

Then sort the keys, and get the min, max using the second tuple element as the key:

```
>>> for hour in sorted(buckets):
...    print hour, max(buckets[hour], key=lambda l: l[1]), min(buckets[hour], key=lambda l: l[1])

0 [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 0, 0), 0.9627101684867109] [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 0, 40), 0.1920554638586589]
1 [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 1, 20), 0.9870880292994234] [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 1, 0), 0.24394390686092926]
2 [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 2, 20), 0.6211085118418351] [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 2, 40), 0.1309246438480619]
3 [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 3, 40), 0.9260473796075621] [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 3, 0), 0.2042948575387714]
4 [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 4, 20), 0.9909948477818202] [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 4, 0), 0.08180604335801178]
5 [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 5, 40), 0.8643323785674638] [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 5, 20), 0.5751211758007434]
6 [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 6, 40), 0.9816449110831348] [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 6, 0), 0.44366887986412196]
7 [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 7, 0), 0.7976769524401801] [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 7, 20), 0.019715644725192494]
8 [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 8, 20), 0.9854650056341737] [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 8, 40), 0.44764478642480565]
9 [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 9, 40), 0.7652296383460859] [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 9, 20), 0.2428205990660569]
10 [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 10, 40), 0.7867821039231312] [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 10, 20), 0.5437523646936837]
11 [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 11, 0), 0.7178834338473005] [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 11, 40), 0.2819549901100772]
12 [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 12, 40), 0.8353818765863841] [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 12, 0), 0.0849398640248602]
13 [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 13, 40), 0.7653484731068122] [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 13, 20), 0.17091634151665247]
14 [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 14, 0), 0.9510280942218504] [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 14, 20), 0.2696780695726898]
15 [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 15, 40), 0.9479268674677883] [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 15, 0), 0.48395825825107863]
16 [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 16, 0), 0.9046641495205922] [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 16, 20), 0.045289391652820865]
17 [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 17, 40), 0.5887496294547572] [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 17, 20), 0.11146542138230242]
18 [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 18, 40), 0.8128833057460692] [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 18, 0), 0.08733136331114111]
19 [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 19, 40), 0.6555892081746738] [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 19, 20), 0.20504702851137402]
20 [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 20, 40), 0.837007721004194] [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 20, 0), 0.7380315441194354]
21 [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 21, 0), 0.8842141478652727] [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 21, 20), 0.3349342531521037]
22 [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 22, 0), 0.8273356582091318] [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 22, 40), 0.13561711047456493]
23 [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 23, 0), 0.8906156794457442] [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 26, 23, 20), 0.2653437814631542]
```

If your data are already in order by the datetime element, you can bypass the separate bucket step and use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> for hour, group in groupby(arr, lambda t: t[0].hour):
...     li=list(group)
...     print hour, max(li, key=lambda l: l[1]), min(li, key=lambda l: l[1])
```